# Vscode on raspberry pi?

Tags: raspbian

Is it possible to install [vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) on Raspberry pi?

Comment: Judging by [search results](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=vscode) it's indeed possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to install VS Code on Raspberry Pi.
Here is an Article:
https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-visual-studio-code/